# Best way to append new number to the `range` list and sort the new list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, range

I've been writing Python for a while. What are the opinions on what is the best way to make these three lines concise?

```
my_range = range(97, 123)     # I want a-z
my_range.append(32)           # I want space as well
my_range = sorted(my_range)   # I want it sorted (whilst not needed)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
import random

count = 0
string = ""

my_range = range(97, 123)
my_range.append(32)
my_range = sorted(my_range)

while len(string) != 27:
    string = string + chr(random.choice(my_range))

print string
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Are you using Python 2? Because otherwise this raises an Error; `range` does not have an `append()` method..

Comment: This is an opinion-oriented question. You look pretty concise here. Some might suggest stacking operations on a single line (i.e. `my_range = sorted(range(97, 123).append(32))` but as you see, while that makes it shorter, it adds complexity and difficulty reading it.

Comment: I do not see a need to sort your range. Why are you doing that?

Comment: I agree, that I don't see the need, but it was in the question that the poster wanted to, so I left it in there. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Single Line Solution

In Python 2.7, in order **to achieve this in single line**, you may simply do:

```
>>> sorted(range(97, 123) + [32])
[32, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122]
```

whereas in Python 3.x, you need to type-cast `range` to `list` as it returns object of `range` type *(which doesn't have `+` operator defined for it)*:

```
>>> sorted(list(range(97, 123)) + [32])
[32, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122]
```

## Performance Efficient Solution *(using [`bisect.bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect))*

However, the **performance efficient way to achieve this** will be using [**`bisect.bisect`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect) which gives the same result without performing *sorting* on the list. This solution is based on the fact that `range` list is already sorted. Hence, insert the new number at the correct position in the sorted list maintaining the [sortedness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sortedness) *(without explicitly sorting the list)*. Below are the example to illustrate the behavior:

```
from bisect import bisect

# Example 1: when new number falls inside the range
my_range = list(range(31, 35))
my_range.insert(bisect(my_range, 32), 32)
# where `my_range` will hold `[31, 32, 32, 33, 34]`

# Example 2: when new number falls before the range
my_range = list(range(97, 102))
my_range.insert(bisect(my_range, 32), 32)
# where `my_range` will hold `[32, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101]`

# Example 3: when new number falls after the range
my_range = list(range(25, 30))
my_range.insert(bisect(my_range, 32), 32)
# where `my_range` will hold `[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 32]`
```

---

## Performance Comparison

Below is the `timeit` comparison of both the above solution in Python 3. As the size of `range` will increase, the time difference between both the solution will increase proportionally.

- using **`sorted(...)`** *(1.91 usec per loop)*

  ```
  mquadri$ python3 -m timeit "sorted(list(range(97, 123)) + [32])"
  100000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 usec per loop
  ```
- using **`bisect.bisect(...)`** *(1.18 usec per loop)*

  ```
  mquadri$ python3 -m timeit -s "from bisect import bisect" "my_range = list(range(97, 123));  my_range.insert(bisect(my_range, 32), 32)"
  1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 usec per loop
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, you can do:

```
>>> my_range = sorted([32]+range(97,123))
>>> my_range
[32, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122]
```